# JdbcTemplate SELECT ... FOR UPDATE - no lock

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am using **JdbcTemplate** from **Spring** framework.

The database is **Oracle**.

Simplified Code:

```
void m() {
    setAutocommit(false); // the same result with/without this line (by default: true )
    JdbcTemplate jt;
    ...
    String selectForUpdateLine = "SELECT X FROM T ... FOR UPDATE";
    int x = jt.queryForList(selectForUpdateLine, objs, types, Smth.class).size();
    ...
    addDelay(); // to be sure that I can simulate 2 consecutive SELECTs (just for test)
    ...
    if ( x == 0 )
        jt.update(insertLine, objs2, types2); // insert
    else
        jt.update(updateLine, objs2, types2); // update
}
```

If I call `m()` twice it executes:

***SELECT > SELECT > INSERT/UPDATE > INSERT/UPDATE***

but I want to have

***SELECT > INSERT/UPDATE > SELECT > INSERT/UPDATE***

I expected to have a lock after the first `SELECT` ( on the strengths of `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` ), but both selects are called, so the `UPDATE/INSERT` doesn't work well.

I also tried to use **`@Transactional`** for the method, trying to have a single transaction that contains both `INSERT` and `UPDATE/INSERT`, but it didn't work.
E.g.:

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

How can I be sure that `SELECT` and `UPDATE/INSERT` will be run together ? (with/without `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, `@Transactional`, etc. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a SELECT FOR UPDATE and then an INSERT or UPDATE can't you just issue a single MERGE statement, and let the database do the hard work for you. You may need to check you have the appropriate Unique Constraints on the table you are merging into e.g.

```
void m() {
    JdbcTemplate jt;
    ...
    jt.update(mergeLine, objs2, types2); // merge
}
```

Comment: MERGE is not atomic and this is why it won't work.
But there is a workaround. If I add UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT, the second MERGE will fail if it tries to insert the same values. But I can do something like this: try { merge(); } catch(Exception e) { update(); }. I'd like to have an ATOMIC MERGE ...

Answer (score 1):

Why did you turn off auto-commit?

```
setAutocommit(false);
```

Since you disabled auto-commit, your `INSERT/UPDATE` will not be executed immediately. So if you call `m()` twice, since it starts with a `SELECT` that will be executed again before the `INSERT/UPDATE` from the previous run will be executed, hence you'll see an execution order:

**SELECT > SELECT > INSERT/UPDATE > INSERT/UPDATE**

You should commit before you return from `m()` or you should go with `@Transactional` but don't disable auto-commit.

Comment: This is why I setAutocommit to false:
Note
Locking of rows for update using SELECT FOR UPDATE only applies when autocommit is disabled (either by beginning transaction with START TRANSACTION or by setting autocommit to 0. If autocommit is enabled, the rows matching the specification are not locked.|
(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/innodb-locking-reads.html)
------------------
But there is the same result without that line: S > S > I/U > I/U

Comment: Yes, rows are only locked if a transaction is in progress. By using `@Transactional` and NOT using `setAutoCommit(false)` you should have the intended execution sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing JDBCTemplate and use simple jdbc statement and see if it locks.